# Runtime context (this) of the function comes from this.props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We always use like this:

```
var MainComponent = React.createClass({
    changeHandler() {
        this.setState({
            foo: 'bar';
        })
    },
    render() {
        return (<SubComponent onChange={this.changeHandler} />)
    }
})
var SubComponent = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (<button onClick={this.props.onChange}>Change</button>)
    }
})
```

when we call `this.props.onChange` in SubComponent, we actually call `changeHandler` of MainComponent.
I suddenly realize that the context of `changeHandler` has been changed when pass to SubComponent using `this.props`, the `this` inside `changeHandler` should have been changed to `this.props`.
But as we all know, when we call `changeHandler` inside Subcomponent, the `this` in `changeHandler` is still MainComponent.
So I guess there may be some 'binding' when when pass function from MainComponent to SubComponent using `this.props`. The context of `changeHandler` is bound to MainComponent.

I add an `console.log(this.props)` in SubComponent's render, and I find some properties been add to `this.props.onChange`:

1. __reactBoundArguments: null
2. __reactBoundContext: point to Constructor MainComponent
3. __reactBoundMethod: point to function changeHandler

I think these are about the 'binding', but I don't know how they actually work.

Could someone please tell me something detail about this context binding, it's really nag me a lot. How does React do that?

Comment: I think your missing the point: the entire purpose of passing the change handler from the parent to the child is so that it uses the parent's `this`. If we wanted to use the child's `this` we would just write the method in the child.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I really want to know how react do that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define your components with `React.createClass()` there's a bit of auto-binding behind the scenes.

Your `onChange={this.changeHander}` effectively becomes `onChange={this.changeHandler.bind(this)}`. The reason for this is because it's generally what you want. This is documented here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html

Note however that if you define your components using the ES6 class syntax, this auto-binding does not occur. This was a deliberate decision to keep the behaviour the same as typical JavaScript classes. This is documented here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html

> #### Autobinding
>
> React.createClass has a built-in magic feature that bound all methods to this automatically for you. This can be a little confusing for JavaScript developers that are not used to this feature in other classes, or it can be confusing when they move from React to other classes.
>
> Therefore we decided not to have this built-in into React's class model. You can still explicitly prebind methods in your constructor if you want.